# Select both sides of Minus operator

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find the difference in table names of each owner for both sides of the minus query.

Say I have 2 select statements from a table and I want to compare them as such:

Select1:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha';
```

Select2:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie';
```

Say alpha's table has table names: a, b, c and charlie's table has table names b,c.

If I do

```
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha') minus    
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie';
```

This gives me the expected result:  a.

Conversely, if I do the opposite:

```
  (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie') minus    
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha';
```

This gives me the expected result: empty row.

Now If I want both the table name 'a' and the empty row I perform:

```
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha') minus 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie'
  Union
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie') minus 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha';
```

then I get nothing.

How would I return the 'a' row and the empty row combined?
I am using Oracle DB

Comment: What name of query of "both-sides minus" would fit the best? I call it "two-way minus". Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use parenthesis after union

```
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha') minus 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie'

  Union
(
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie') minus 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha'
)
```

example

```
with t1 as
(
select 62054 as  sample_id,'2018-09-25 10:18:15' as timestamp,2652 as p_id from dual
union all
select 62054 as  sample_id,'2018-09-27 16:44:57' as timestamp,966 as p_id from dual
union all
select 62046 as  sample_id,null ,1809 as p_id from dual
union all
select 62046 , '018-09-25 10:18:15' ,2097  from dual



) select * from t1 where p_id=2652
 minus
 select * from t1 where p_id=966
 union

 select * from t1 where p_id=2652
 minus
 select * from t1 where p_id=2652
```

the above will return null
but

```
with t1 as
(
select 62054 as  sample_id,'2018-09-25 10:18:15' as timestamp,2652 as p_id from dual
union all
select 62054 as  sample_id,'2018-09-27 16:44:57' as timestamp,966 as p_id from dual
union all
select 62046 as  sample_id,null ,1809 as p_id from dual
union all
select 62046 , '018-09-25 10:18:15' ,2097  from dual



) select * from t1 where p_id=2652
 minus
 select * from t1 where p_id=966
 union
(
 select * from t1 where p_id=2652
 minus
 select * from t1 where p_id=2652
 )
```

the above will return below

```
SAMPLE_ID   TIMESTAMP   P_ID
62054   2018-09-25 10:18:15 2652
```

Comment: What name of query of "both-sides minus" would fit the best? I call it "two-way minus". Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want is `UNION` `MINUS` `INTERSECT`, if you get what I mean? Compute the union, compute the intersect, and do a `MINUS` between those two result sets (using appropriate parentheses, which is where your current efforts are failing because `UNION` and `MINUS` have the same precedence)

```
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha' UNION 
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie')
MINUS
(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'charlie' INTERSECT
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'alpha');
```

This, I believe, correctly reflects what you're *logically* asking for. [Zaynul Abadin Tuhin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632659/15498) addresses the immediate issue. But I believe your effort (and their fix) obscures the *intent* here.

Comment: What name of query of "both-sides minus" would fit the best? I call it "two-way minus". Any ideas? :-)

Comment: @JakubP - In Set terms, it's the ["Symmetric difference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations)